# Why should asteroid coming towards a star deflect away from star if gravity is an attractive force?

Tags: forces, planets

I was finding the closest approach of an asteroid  (whose energy is sufficient to exit the gravitational field of the star )so that it can escape the gravitational field of the planet .The asteroid has a velocity and is being attracted by the planet and is leaving the star. Why should it deflect away from the star like this if gravitational force is attractive?
Well I think if I mention the whole question it'll useful so the question is

> An asteroid is approaching a star of radius r . The impact parameter is b . Find the minimum value of b for which asteroid will just escape on falling into the star.

My instructor said the drawing should be

[image]

Why it shouldn't deflect like this?
Instructor said if this happens then it will be orbiting the planet.

[image]

Comment: Why would the first drawing be happening? Did you read this somewhere?

Comment: @Steeven I am asking as the instructor said this.

Comment: My guess is that the comet is actually in orbit around another celestial body and that the planet in the picture simply alters that slightly, but as you said, the velocity is enough to leave the influence of the planet and thus the comet moves away around its original object.

Comment: Maybe your instructor was talking about the "stone skipping" effect, when the atmosphere acts in the same way as water does when throwing flat stones at a sharp angle. This is explained here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/3072 I do not know how pronounced this effect is, and this answer also mentions that the curve might be wider but never inverted (unless the atmosphere is very dense on some other planet maybe).

Comment: I thik that first drawing is incorrect it should encircle the planet acc. to me

Comment: @DakkVader i said that the asteroid has enough velocity to escape as in the question it has to escape and I think a central force does not increase asteroids velocity in direction of it is leaving. If I'm incorrect then suggestions to improve question is always acceptable.

Comment: I'm thinking like this, https://imgur.com/a/FsNEhnh , could this be the case? Does the assignment say anything like this? If you only have the one body, your second image is the correct one.

Comment: I saw just now that since i left my first answer you've updated the question. You can disregard my beautiful image.

Comment: Fire your instructor and get a new one!

Comment: In light of new evidence (updated question), I agree with @knzhou.

Comment: @knzhou well I had to say tuition teacher. Sorry.

Comment: @DakkVader Helping is helping.  Thanks for the help.  And your idea was beautiful. Might help me in some encounters.  So please keep your comment.

Comment: @Nobodyrecognizeable I will of course leave it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one thinks of the conic sections which are the solutions of the gravitational equations between two bodies, it is clear that one of the two bodies, the massive one, should be sitting in one of the [focuses](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~thompson/161/orbits.html) of the section:

[image: conic]

The top image in your answer does not correspond to this. The lower does.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of angular momentum conservation.  Basically, the motion in the $r$ coordinate is not only controlled by the gravitational potential $V(r)$ but really by the so-called [effective potential](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential)
$$
V_{\hbox{eff}}=\frac{\ell^2}{2\mu r^2}+V(r)
$$
where $\ell$ is the angular momentum of the system.  Since the gravitational potential is in $1/r$, it is the centrifugal term $\ell^2/(2\mu r^2)$ that dominates at small distance, and this is a strongly repulsive potential that “pushes back” the particles towards larger values of $r$, preventing the particle from reaching $r=0$ unless the angular momentum $\ell=0$, i.e unless the particle is directly approaching the planet.

When the particle is far away, the $\ell^2/(2\mu r^2)$ term is negligible compared to the gravitational potential so the motion looks purely attractive.

Comment: So are you saying the first figure is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The object curves towards the planet: your second drawing is correct.  If you want the asymptotic directions to be as in the first drawing, the object would pass on the other side of the planet.